# Need to disable a checkbox in JSP where checkbox name is same as hidden field

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a checkbox and a hidden input type having same name. I need to enable/disable checkbox base on some condition. How can i do that ? If I am trying to disable it by using checkbox name it is failing because it is not able to identify whether I want to diasable hidden field or checkbox.

Please suggest any solution for this.

Comment: why not use an unique id?

Comment: Please post some relevant code. Are you using jQuery?

Comment: function updateDrmCheckboxes(parent_checkbox){
    document.ilform.one_more_checkbox.disabled=(!parent_checkbox.checked);
    document.ilform.checkbox_hiddenField.disabled=(!parent_checkbox.checked);

Answer (score 3):

try this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getElements() {
  var x=document.getElementsByName("x");

  if(x.length == 2) {
    alert("Number of 'X' is " + x.length);
    document.getElementsByName("x")[1].disabled=true ;
  } 

}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input name="x" type="hidden" value="1">
<input name="x" type="text" value="1">

<input type="button" onclick="getElements()" value="How many elements named 'x'?">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you insist to use `name` instead of of an unique `id`

By assuming your `tag` order with same `name` in your `html` is looked something like below:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="a">
<input type = "hidden" name="a">
```

You can do something like this:

```
document.getElementsByName('a')[0].disabled = true;
```

Comment: I presume OP do not want an unique `id` solution and insist want to get the element by `name` and assume he only want `JS` solution.